# MariaDB removing backslashes from string in UPDATE query

Tags: mariadb

I've an issue with a very basic query using MariaDB 10.3. I'm updating thousands of path in a database with this code:

```
UPDATE il1_il8_localisation i SET i.`IL_17_CODE_PHOTO_1`="..\IPB\Photos\Foto1_261_ 3837.jpg" WHERE i.`IQ_1_NUMERO_DU_QUESTIONNAIRE`= 261;
```

and it fills the column `IL_17_CODE_PHOTO_1` with the string
`..IPBPhotosFoto1_     261_ 3837.jpg` instead of `..\IPB\Photos\Foto1_     261_ 3837.jpg`

I tried to change data sturcture from `varchar(120)` to `TEXT` with no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MariaDB uses the backslash character (`\`) as an escape character.](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/string-literals/) From the linked article:

> Backslash (`\`), if not used as an escape character, **must always be escaped.** When followed by a character that is not [a valid escape sequence], backslashes **will simply be ignored.**

Replace each single backslash with a double backslash (to escape the escape character):

```
UPDATE il1_il8_localisation i SET i.IL_17_CODE_PHOTO_1="..\\IPB\\Photos\\Foto1_ 261_ 3837.jpg" WHERE i.IQ_1_NUMERO_DU_QUESTIONNAIRE= 261;
```

Comment: Thank you very much @esqew for your support. Issue solved.